# wp_insert_post() with HTML tags using PHP

Tags: php, html, wp-insert-post

This question seem to be unanswered. I find myself stuck on it. Here it goes

I've a problem with WP API to insert a post with HTML Tags.

I'm using the method: **wp_insert_post()** and the content is like this:

`$content = "<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>";`

The result I want when I publish the post is:

**A formatted post applying the html where necessary.**

But the result I have when I publish the post is:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

**When I go to the WP Editor to edit the same POST Directly, The Visual Editor looks well formatted as expected**

And The then I navigate to Text Editor as see this well formatted too:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

It's quite obvious that this is what I actually want. But When I do this post from my php file  as stated earlier, I get this published:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

**MY CODE**

```
$content="<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>";

$my_post = array( 
'post_title' => $title, 
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'post_content' => $content,
'post_author' => 1, 
'post_category' => array(8,39)); 

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

**I HAVE TRIED**
`html_entity_decode($content);`

And

```
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');

remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

Before Inserting to DB and

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');

add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

After The insert

My script only have the `wp-load.php` loaded.

here is what I get with my real code... it seem it is inside `<pre><code> $content </code></pre>` for some reason... I really need help with it:

[image]

UPDATE: I checked my database and the post includes this line `<pre><code>` then the **post** itself `</code></pre>` And I'm thinking if there's a way to get rid of those It might work pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to wrap you `wp_insert_post` call like bellow:

```
 kses_remove_filters(); //This Turns off kses
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
 kses_init_filters(); //This Turns on kses again
```

So I tried your code with my method and it perfectly worked. Here is what I did.

```
$title = "My news";
$content='<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>';

$postData = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'         =>   'post',
    'post_category' => array()
);

kses_remove_filters();
$id = wp_insert_post($postData);
kses_init_filters();
```

It worked perfectly as it should. I'm using **Twenty Twenty** theme with no plugin enabled.

Comment: I think I've also tried this.. But to be sure of your suggestions... There would be no need for ```html_entity_decode($content);``` before the wrapping right?. And there's no need to call the ```kses.php``` from ```wp-include``` right?

Comment: Update: After trying your solution, I get the same results as in the screenshot I shared with one difference. The ```""``` (quotations) in all tags are stripped off

Comment: I've added the code I used to test. And the code I mentioned above worked for me without any issue.

Comment: No need to include anything. Just those code in functions.php that's what all I did to test.

Comment: I have a bunch of plugins installed. I can't basically disable all... What plugin do you think might cause this code not to work as expected, the editors?

Comment: Apparently the plugin dealing with me was **Jetpack** I had to disable ```markups``` in ```Writing``` and all problems solved... I'll give you an up vote when ever I can... Thanks..